# In SAPUI5 List Report Application, the updated value does not reflect until reload the list

Tags: listview, odata, sapui5, refresh, manifest.json

In my SAPUI5 List Report Application project, from the List view, when I navigate to the detailed page (General Information), click Edit and change one of the value in a drop-down (which has a value Help) and click Save, it does not update the description. It updates only the code.

eg; When I change the confirmation Status from "(P) Paid" to "Initial" and save, it updates as "Paid". Note that "Paid" is the description and "P" is the code. So I can see the "P" has removed, but "Paid" text still there.

Also when you go back to the previous screen (List view) then the Confirmation Status of the list shows "Paid". But if you click the "Go" button and then the List refreshes and show the status shows as "Initial" which is correct.

Refer below screenshots.

Figure 1: Here I change the Status from "(P) Paid" from "Initial".
[image]

Figure 2: This is what I see after save.
[image]

Figure 3: List view did not update too.
[image]

Figure 4: If you click the "Go" button, then you will see the correct output.
[image]

Any idea why it does not update?

Note that I have created a SAPUI5 List Report Application project using Project From Template option in my web IDE.

Also, I have set the "refreshAfterChange" property as true in the manifest.json under "models". But it does not help.

```
"": {
            "dataSource": "mainService",
            "settings": {
                "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay",
                "defaultCountMode": "Inline",
                "refreshAfterChange": true
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExtensionAPI.refreshAncestors()` might solve your issue. [See official documentation for more information.](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.suite.ui.generic.template.ObjectPage.extensionAPI.ExtensionAPI%23methods/refreshAncestors)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Use `oModel.refresh();` to force the update after changing data.